# Firefox returns HTTP 200 although it is 401

Tags: php, firefox, request, http-status-codes

I have a PHP coding which should return 401. It does so in Chrome, IE, Edge. Only Firefox displays 200 instead of 401 and I don't get why.

```
<?php
http_response_code(401);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode([
        "status" => 401,
        "message" => "some message",
        "data" => ['some' => 'data']
    ]);
?>
```

Literally all browsers give me 401 Unauthorized which is what I expect and should be correct. Only Firefox displays `HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established` for that request. What is that? Why?

Comment: Firefox 67.0.4 gives me 401

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you on?

Comment: Firefox 72.0.2 (64-Bit)

Comment: that's not the full script, is it?

Comment: @delboy1978uk yes it is full script